# Keyboard not working properly, misprinting (Misfirering) on few keys

Tags: keyboard

Even after cleaning, I have a keyboard which is not working properly, typing © instead of g, or m instead of SPACE u is not functioning at all but showing up together with [  (like this u[ ) and actually misprinting on many other keys.

It is not a cleaning issue, and there are no signs of why will such think happens!

Comment: Try another keyboard, try that keyboard on another computer.

Comment: Sounds like your keyboard mapping is wrong in software. What OS are using?

Comment: I use Macs, and it is the same problem on both computers with OS 10